# Oracle BI Publisher: Error 'Failed to load: io/designer/inline-preview-crosstab'

Tags: oracle, pivot-table, bi-publisher

I have a report with a standard layout - created via the layout wizard. The report is working fine but when i tried to edit the layout I receive the following error:

failed to load:io/designer/inline-preview-crosstab on Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.9.0

Error is shown when layout contain pivot table. Does not matter if you edit layout or want to create new.

I restarted my Bi publisher and I cleaned cache.

Can anybody help me?

[error_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg6qN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and see if "Use 11.1.1.5 compatibility mode" is set to 'True', if yes set it to "False'. This setting is found in Administration--> Runtime Configuration --> Properties

If you have a support identifier with Oracle refer this support doc. Oracle Support Document 2138721.1

Comment: George! Thank you for your help. I changed value to 'False' and layouts works again. But without this option 'Use 11.1.1.5 compatibility mode' set to 'True' in Excel numeric value is not editable. I think its time to upgrade my BI to ver. 12.